# How to select distinct values from 2 tables and then using Order By

Tags: sql, sorting

- Table1: SchoolCode, SchoolName
- Table2: SchoolCode, Mascot

I want to join tables to select distinct `SchoolName`. I have this SQL query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT SchoolName
FROM Table1
JOIN Table2 ON Table1.SchoolCode = Table2.SchoolCode
WHERE Mascot = 'Rangers'
```

If I want to sort the `SchoolName`, where do I use `ORDER BY`?

Tried using `ORDER BY` at the end, but it did not sort my SchoolNames

Comment: `SELECT DISTINCT SchoolName FROM Table1 JOIN Table2 ON Table1.SchoolCode = Table2.SchoolCode WHERE Table2.Mascot = 'Rangers' order by Table1.SchoolName DESC;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Order by is the usually last clause of a select statement, unless these is some limit/offset-fetch (pagination) applied to the result :

```
-- WITH
SELECT DISTINCT
    SchoolName 
-- INTO
FROM Table1 
JOIN Table2 ON Table1.SchoolCode = Table2.SchoolCode 
WHERE Mascot = 'Rangers'
-- GROUP BY
-- HAVING
ORDER BY 
    SchoolName 
-- LIMIT
```

NB: there are some dbms specific implementation of limit (e.g. MS SQL Server uses "top(n)" and that qualifies the select clause.

Comment: Great! Pleased to hear it. Perhaps now read this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer only you can "accept" an answer to your question, and it helps the site by signifying that an answer exists to that question.